# Malformed image while exporting to PDF from JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have an image that is embedded in my report. Locally (via JasperReports Studio) everything works fine. I can export image in any format to any output format and everything is in order.

However, when I deploy my report on JRS (with image) I'm getting something like this

[image]

, when image is in bmp format.

When I convert image to png or jpg and then I deploy it on the JRS I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR EngineServiceImpl,pool-5-thread-179:598 - Error while exporting report to PDF
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array 
is not a recognized imageformat.
```

Any clues?

EDIT:
I use JasperStudio, here's the configuration of img element:
[image]

```
    <image>
        <reportElement x="200" y="50" width="120" height="111" uuid="03e9bde6-8ddd-4b0e-b3c7-8d44b4d71ff9"/>
        <imageExpression><![CDATA["Images/hidden_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
    </image>
```

Comment: What is the code of image element?

Comment: No code really. I use JasperStudi. I've added the conf of the element.

Comment: I mean the part of *jrxml* file related to the *image* element

Comment: Sorry, I thought you assumed that I am generating from Java. Added - nothing fancy here.

Comment: Usually the expression for JRS looks like `repo:/reports/images/logo.png`. Did you try to use `repo`?

Comment: It's changed to "repo:", when I am publishing report (and image itself) on the server. However, when I was performing some other tests yesterday I was able to get proper image in the ouput. I suppose the point is that in JStudio I have embed images directly from the server, not locally. I will check that later during the day and if it works I will post an answer.

Comment: You can view the valid path of resource on JRS with help of Properties dialog